# Encode & symbol in XML

Tags: xml, perl

My Perl program is processing an XML file. Some entries may contain & symbols. And the parser breaks, saying: "Invalid name in entity".

How can I process the file and encode &-s in all the incorrect entities?

So, it will be something like this:

```
<words>text1 & text2</words>  -->  <words>text1 &amp; text2</words>
```

Comment: Do you want to fix the file by hand or support ill-formed XML in your program?

Comment: I want to support ill-formed XML, that is created by hand. Making it valid XML.

Comment: If you use XML::LibXML, I think it's `recover` parser option will allow you to ignore those errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's tricky, non-trivial, and usually involves tradeoffs. When I encountered a similar problem, replacing `&` characters followed by either an uppercase character or whitespace (`/\&[A-Z ]/` in regexp) with `&amp;` (and the "trailing character") solved most cases -- and it's usually good enough since you're already going the extra mile by accepting not well-formed XML input.

Comment: In XML it's legal to declare an entity with a capitol letter like `&A;`, A better way to munge the document into XML is to use a negative assertion that the `&` is not followed by what might be a valid entity name. `s/&(?![[:alpha:]_:][\w.:-]*;)/&amp;/` This doesn't quite catch all the Unicode cases in the XML standard but it's basically close enough.

Answer (score 6):

It's not an XML file. If it were XML, the `&` would be written as `&amp;`. Processing non-XML files is difficult because you can't use an XML parser. It's best to fix the program that created this file, changing it to produce proper well-formed XML.